# specified cast is not valid c#. When I want to map

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-6, c#-3.0

```
qData.col1 = (int?) eReader["col1"] != null? (int?)eReader["col1"] : null;
qData.col1_per = (decimal?)eReader["col1_per"];
qData.col2 = (int?)eReader["col2"];
qData.col2_per = (decimal?)eReader["col2_per"];
```

//I want to map but when data is null then i get error. like this...qData.col1 = (int?) eReader["col1"];
//Please help how can solve this problem.

Comment: Would you please explain more?

Comment: I want to cast like this way.....    qData.col1 = (int?) eReader["col1"] ; this approach is right till when data is valid .... however if i get any null value form database then .. I face this problem....."Specified cast is not valid."

Comment: I think it will be (int?)eReader["col1"] : 0 instead of (int?)eReader["col1"] : null

Comment: Thanks for your response.... however if put 0 instead of null then my all call calculation is fall in down ....I need if I get null then it should be null and if i get 0 then it is 0.  Because .... My business represent if data is 0 that means there is attempt to action and when data is null it means user doesn't any action.

Comment: Is qData.col1 nullable?

Comment: yeah it is nullable

Comment: try (int?)null in (int?)eReader["col1"] : (int?)null

Comment: Is `eReader["col1"]` a nullable type?

Comment: yeah it is also nullable

Comment: Didn't encounter the problem you describe in my tests, it worked fine. I can't reproduce your problem based on the code you provided. Please provide a [minimum reproducible unit](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). @Rakib Ahasan